# Visual studio 2013 DLL Project: Dialog form not displayed while running the DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have a Visual Studio 2013 C++ DLL project.

The build DLL works fine, except one point: There is a lack of interactive form which should open when DLL starts & it should be responsive to/from the DLL

I had referred to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2dac35d4-95b6-4f27-8517-1b403aca2360/add-a-form-to-dll?forum=vcgeneral)

I tried:
***Right click on Project-> Select Add->Resource->Dialog***

After that, a blank Dialog box appeared in the Visual Studio tab and it was listed in the **Resources** folder

1. I thought simply compiling the project would make the empty Dialog box display while running the DLL.
   But even the empty Dialog box is not displayed when I run the DLL

Am I missing something here?

2. Also, would C++ be sufficient to add functionality to the form/Dialog? Or, any other language like C#?
   (So that I may add event handling kind of functionality to that)

Comment: 1) Windows and dialogs do not open by themselves, you'll need to add code to do that. Refer to the overview at [Using Dialog Boxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes) and decide whether you want a modal vs. modeless dialog, then you can find code samples for either case to get started. 2) Win32 is a C API, so you can certainly do everything in C or C++.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks & I would also like to know about forms

Comment: "Forms" is not a well-defined term, and "Windows Forms" is a .NET platform not usually associated with C++. If you just want a window or dialog based GUI, there are many [VC++ samples](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could use MFC to add functionality to the form/Dialog.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a MFC DLL named 'CTestDll', and select `Regular DLL using shared MFC DLL`
   [image]
2. Then select `Add->Resource->Dialog`
3. Add code in CTestDll.cpp

   > ```
   > #include "CTestDlg.h"
   >
   >  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Show()
   > {
   >   AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
   >   CTestDlg test;
   >   test.DoModal();
   > }
   > ```
4. Create a MFC App for testing. You could call it through the button click event.

[image]

```
void CMFCApplication3Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    typedef void (WINAPI *TESTDLL)();
    HINSTANCE hInstance = LoadLibrary(_T("CTestDll.dll")); // 
    if (hInstance != NULL)
    {
        TESTDLL TestShow = (TESTDLL)GetProcAddress(hInstance, "Show");

        if (TestShow != NULL)
        {
            TestShow();
        }
        FreeLibrary(hInstance);
    }

}
```